# Field Change Listener for Custom ListView in Blackberry?

Tags: listview, blackberry

I am working in an application where I have to show Contacts in a list view. I have created the list view with the help of Vertical Field Manager and Label Fields.

I have an Email field and Phone number field on which I have to call a on click listener.

I have implemented the listener on my class but it failed for a click event. Do not show any click event.

Currently, I am working with the below code:

```
public class CustomListView extends VerticalFieldManager implements FieldChangeListener{
    private VerticalFieldManager mVFM=null;

    private Font _allFonts=null;
    private Font _headingFonts=null;

    /**
     * @param resultVec
     */
    public CustomListView() {
        super(VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
        setMargin(0, 0, 10, 0);

        int resolutionWidth = Display.getWidth(); // PLANNING FOR THREE FIXED RESOLUTIONS 320, 360 AND 480
        //HANDLE WITH THE CODE DIFFERENT DEVICES
        if(resolutionWidth>=480){
            _allFonts = ApplicationFont.explainationFont_18;
            _headingFonts = ApplicationFont.labelFont_18;
        }else if(resolutionWidth >=360){
            _allFonts = ApplicationFont.explainationFont_18;
            _headingFonts = ApplicationFont.labelFont_18;
        }else{//RESOLUTION WIDTH <=320
            _allFonts = ApplicationFont.explainationFont_15;
            _headingFonts = ApplicationFont.labelFont_15;
        }

        int maxLength = Constants.Country_List.length;
        int minLength = 0;
        if(maxLength >= 0){
            for (int i = minLength; i < maxLength; i++) {
                VerticalFieldManager vfm = getVerticalFieldManager();
                vfm.setMargin(0, 10, 0, 10);

                LabelField countryLabel = new LabelField();
                countryLabel.setText(Constants.Country_List[i]);
                //countryLabel.setFont(_allFonts);
                countryLabel.setMargin(10, 0, 10, 0);
                HorizontalFieldManager countryHFM = new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
                countryHFM.add(countryLabel);
                countryHFM.setBackground(BackgroundFactory
                        .createSolidBackground(Constants.LightGreyBgColorCode));

                LabelField addressLabel = new LabelField();
                addressLabel.setText(Constants.Address_List[i]);
                //addressLabel.setFont(_allFonts);

                LabelField stateLabel = new LabelField();
                stateLabel.setText(Constants.State_List[i]);
                //  stateLabel.setFont(_allFonts);

                LabelField cityLabel = new LabelField(){
                    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                        graphics.setColor(Constants.DarkGreyTextColorCode);
                        super.paint(graphics);
                    }
                };
                cityLabel.setText(Constants.City_List[i]);
                //cityLabel.setFont(_allFonts);

                LabelField phoneLabel = new LabelField(){
                    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                        graphics.setColor(Constants.DarkGreyTextColorCode);
                        super.paint(graphics);
                    }
                };
                phoneLabel.setText("Phone(s):");
                //phoneLabel.setFont(_allFonts);

                LabelField numLabel = new LabelField(){
                    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                        graphics.setColor(Constants.blueTextColor);
                        super.paint(graphics);
                    }
                };
                numLabel.setText(Constants.Phone_List[i]);
                //numLabel.setFont(_allFonts);

                HorizontalFieldManager phoneNumberHFM = new HorizontalFieldManager();
                phoneNumberHFM.add(phoneLabel);
                phoneNumberHFM.add(numLabel);

                LabelField emailLabel = new LabelField(){
                    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                        graphics.setColor(Constants.DarkGreyTextColorCode);
                        super.paint(graphics);
                    }
                };
                emailLabel.setText("Email:");
                //emailLabel.setFont(_allFonts);

                LabelField emailIdLabel = new LabelField(){
                    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                        graphics.setColor(Constants.blueTextColor);
                        super.paint(graphics);
                    }
                };
                emailIdLabel.setText(Constants.Email_List[i]);
                //emailIdLabel.setFont(_allFonts);

                HorizontalFieldManager emailIdHFM = new HorizontalFieldManager();
                emailIdHFM.add(emailLabel);
                emailIdHFM.add(emailIdLabel);


                mVFM = new  VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH /*|FOCUSABLE*/);
                mVFM.setMargin(20, 0, 20, 0);
                mVFM.add(countryHFM);
                mVFM.add(addressLabel);
                mVFM.add(stateLabel);
                mVFM.add(cityLabel);
                mVFM.add(phoneNumberHFM);
                mVFM.add(emailIdHFM);
                mVFM.add(new NullField(FOCUSABLE));

                vfm.add(mVFM);
                /*SeparatorField separater = new SeparatorField(Constants.LightGreyBgColorCode);
                separater.setMargin(0, 10, 0, 10);*/
                vfm.add(new SeparatorField(Constants.LightGreyBgColorCode));
                add(vfm);
            }
        }
    }

    private VerticalFieldManager getVerticalFieldManager() {
        VerticalFieldManager verticalFieldManager = new VerticalFieldManager(
                VerticalFieldManager.FOCUSABLE
                | VerticalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER
                | VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL
                | VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {

            protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
                if (message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.CLICK) {
                    navigationClick(0, 0);
                }
                return super.touchEvent(message);
            }

            public boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                fieldChangeNotify(1);
                return true;
            }

            protected void onFocus(int direction) {
                super.onFocus(direction);
                setBackground(BackgroundFactory
                        .createSolidBackground(/*0x186DEF*/Constants.WhiteBgColorCode));
                invalidate();
            }

            protected void onUnfocus() {
                super.onUnfocus();
                setBackground(BackgroundFactory
                        .createSolidBackground(Constants.WhiteBgColorCode));
                invalidate();
            }
        };      
        return verticalFieldManager;
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    }
}
```

Please suggest, how can I build a click listener for my list view.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not completely understood what is needed for a FieldChangeListener.

Here is a simple implementation using a FieldChangeListener (note this will only work on OS 5.0 and above as ZoomScreen was not available before then).

```
public MyScreen() {        
    // Set the displayed title of the screen       
    setTitle("Test ZoomScreen");
    ButtonField zoomButton = new ButtonField("Zoom Screen Test");
    FieldChangeListener listener=new FieldChangeListener() {
        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            EncodedImage ei = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("Koala.jpg");
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new ZoomScreen(ei));
        }
    };
    zoomButton.setChangeListener(listener);
    add(zoomButton);
}
```

The important steps are:

1. Create the Field you are listening for changes on - in this case,
   the zoomButton.
2. Create the FieldChangeListener - in this case, a separate class
   that just does the listening, note that the listening is done in the
   fieldChanged() method.
3. Connect the FieldChangeListener to the Field it is listening to -
   in this case we do a setChangeListener on the zoomButton.

I think if you review this implementation, you will see that you have missed out some of the steps, specifically you seem to have done (1), but not (2) or (3).  Rather than me correcting your code, I suggest that you use the insight that I hope the above has given you, and correct your own code.  Good luck.